# How to store .mov format files in firebase storage?

Tags: swift

I have created a button when I click on the button it should open gallery and selects the video and should store that video url in firebase storage but I am getting the above error

> Failed to issue sandbox extension for file file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/PluginKitPlugin/E1B2BE28-9798-42E5-8492-344AA7A3E355/tmp/trim.B8E2D7A4-8D64-4855-B326-53C8D8BA8FEB.MOV, errno = 1

```
@IBAction func gallery(_ sender: Any) {

    imagePickerController.sourceType = .savedPhotosAlbum
    imagePickerController.delegate = self
    imagePickerController.mediaTypes = ["public.movie"]
    present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}



func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    print("entered into picker")


    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    guard let mediaURL = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.mediaURL] as? URL else { return }
    print("info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.mediaURL]",info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.mediaURL])
    print("mediaURL is",mediaURL)

    let storageReference = Storage.storage().reference().child("child/video7.mov")
    // Start the video storage process
    storageReference.putFile(from: mediaURL as URL, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in
        if error == nil {
            print("mediaurl is",mediaURL)
            print("Successful video upload of mediaurl")

            self.removeSpinner()

            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showVideo", sender: mediaURL)

        } else {
            print(error?.localizedDescription as Any)

        }
    })
    // You can do whatever youo want here....
}
```